# How to define SYB functions for type extension for tertiary type constructors (ext3)?

Tags: haskell, generic-programming, scrap-your-boilerplate

In the [Scrap Your Boilerplate package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/syb-0.3.7), in [`Data.Generics.Aliases`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/syb/0.3.7/doc/html/Data-Generics-Aliases.html), there are functions to allow type extension for unary, and binary type constructors.  In particular, there are definitions for [`ext1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/syb/0.3.7/doc/html/Data-Generics-Aliases.html#v%3aext1R) and [`ext2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/syb/0.3.7/doc/html/Data-Generics-Aliases.html#v%3aext2R).

Now, `ext1` and `ext2` are defined in terms of [`dataCast1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Data.html#v%3adataCast1), and [`dataCast2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Data.html#v%3adataCast1), which are part of the [`Data`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Data.html#t%3aData) type class, and are usually defined by the `DeriveDataTypeable` machinery.  But, there's no `dataCast3`, so I don't see an easy way to define `ext3`.

Is it possible to define `ext3`, and if so, how?

Comment: Also note that [gcast1](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Typeable.html#v:gcast1) and [gcast2](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Typeable.html#v:gcast2) exist, but nothing higher.

Comment: @Tinctorius Yes, and it's easy to define `gcast3`, but I don't think there's enough type information outside the `Data` instance in order to define `ext3` in terms of `gcast3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this isn't sufficient. But it feels darn close.

```
ext3 :: (Data a, Typeable3 t)
     => c a
     -> (forall d1 d2 d3. c (t d1 d2 d3))
     -> c a
ext3 def ext = maybe def (id) (gcast3' ext)

gcast3' :: (Typeable3 t, Data a) => c (t f g h) -> Maybe (c a)
gcast3' x = r
 where
  r = if typeOf3 (getArg x) == typeOf3' (getArg (fromJust r))
       then Just $ unsafeCoerce x
       else Nothing
  getArg :: c x -> x
  getArg = undefined
  typeOf3' z = mkTyConApp (typeRepTyCon (typeOf z)) []
```

Comment: On GHC 8.4, this doesn't compile anymore.

Comment: Even this simple function doesn't work:

`thing :: (Typeable t) => (forall b c d . (Data b, Data c, Data d) => f (t b c d)) -> TypeRep`
`thing = typeRep`
GHC says:
`error:
    * Could not deduce (Data b0)           
      from the context: Typeable t         
        bound by the type signature for:   
                   thing :: forall (t :: * -> * -> * -> *) (f :: * -> *).
                            Typeable t =>  
                            (forall b c d. (Data b, Data c, Data d) => f (t b c d)) -> TypeRep
        [...]
      The type variable `b0' is ambiguous
`